# PHP don't find cookies created by JS in another folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am trying to create cookies with JS and send them to PHP script with AJAX requst which is in different folder on the same host.
JS : The script is in home/ directory

```
document.cookie = "sender="+sender;
document.cookie = "getId="+parseIDs[count - 1];
document.cookie = "buildFor="+cmd;
```

PHP : The script is in home/Lib/PHP

```
$sender = $_COOKIE['sender'];
$getId = $_COOKIE['getId'];
$getCmd = $_COOKIE['buildFor'];
```

And I am calling the JS function from HTML in folder home/Lib/User/UserName with onload event.
It works pretty good if I try to call the function from html which is in the same folder as the PHP script.

Comment: need to set cookie `path`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found how to solve this problem.
When you create a cookie you have to make it "global" for the domain you want to use it.
Here is the way how to make that :

```
document.cookie = "COOKIE_NAME="+COOKIE_VALUE+";domain=.DOMAIN;path=/";
```

This simple thing took me 2 hours.. :D